# Condition to swap slot to production in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I use an azure devops yml pipeline to deploy a webapp to an app service.

The same pipeline can be used for different environments. Some of them have an app service with a staging slot, others don't.

To deploy the webapp I use this yml:

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: '$(WebAppName)'
    ResourceGroupName: '$(ResourceGroupName)'
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    SlotName: '$(SlotName)'
    packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/MyProject.zip'
    enableXmlTransform: true
```

So I tried to condition the swap to production if the slot where the app is deployed is not 'production'. But my condition doesn't work.

I have tried this:

```
- task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
  displayName: 'Swap Slots to production'
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne('$(SlotName)', 'production'))
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
    Action: 'Swap Slots'
    WebAppName: '$(WebAppName)'
    ResourceGroupName: '$(ResourceGroupName)'
    SourceSlot: '$(SlotName)'
```

or this:

```
- ${{ if ne(variables.SlotName, 'production') }}: 
  - task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
    displayName: 'Swap Slots to production'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
      Action: 'Swap Slots'
      WebAppName: '$(WebAppName)'
      ResourceGroupName: '$(ResourceGroupName)'
      SourceSlot: '$(SlotName)'
```

The $() variables comes from a variable group loaded depending on the environment to deploy.

The result is always the same:

```
##[error]Error: Source and target slot cannot be same
```

Which means that my condition doesn't work and the task is executed.

Any idea why the swap to production is always called ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used wrong syntax in your condition. Please try this

```
- task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
  displayName: 'Swap Slots to production'
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['SlotName'], 'production'))
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
    Action: 'Swap Slots'
    WebAppName: '$(WebAppName)'
    ResourceGroupName: '$(ResourceGroupName)'
    SourceSlot: '$(SlotName)'
```

And this expression `- ${{ if ne(variables.SlotName, 'production') }}:`  is compile time expression so variable SlotName could be not available at that moment).